# Vector of vectors of T in template<T> class

Tags: c++, templates, vector, std, stdvector

Why this code does not compile (Cygwin)?

```
#include <vector>

template <class Ttile>
class Tilemap
{
    typedef std::vector< Ttile > TtileRow;
    typedef std::vector< TtileRow > TtileMap;
    typedef TtileMap::iterator TtileMapIterator; // error here
};
```

> error: type `std::vector<std::vector<Ttile, std::allocator<_CharT> >, std::allocator<std::vector<Ttile, std::allocator<_CharT> > > >' is not derived from type`Tilemap'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `TtileMap::iterator` is not known to be a type yet. Add the `typename` keyword to fix it

```
typedef typename TtileMap::iterator TtileMapIterator;
```